# how to use GetClusterInformation() function in clusapidll

Tags: c#, pinvoke, cluster-computing

I want to use `GetClusterInformation()` function to get the version of MSCS . 
below is the code snippet I am trying. Any help is much appreciated.

Using Pinvoke would help and is there any class in c# available for doing the same .

```
public static class Test_LoadLibrary
{
    [DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string lpFileName);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr GetProcAddress(IntPtr hModule, string procedureName);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    static extern bool FreeLibrary(IntPtr hModule);

    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    private delegate IntPtr TestOpenCluster(string computerName);

    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public delegate void MyFunctionDelegate(IntPtr frame, string ClusterName, ref uint dword,           ref CLUSTERVERSIONINFO pclusterInfo);

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public class CLUSTERVERSIONINFO {
    public uint dwVersionInfoSize;
    public ushort MajorVersion;
    public ushort MinorVersion;
    public ushort BuildNumber;
    public char[] szVendorId;
    public char[] szCSDVersion;
    public uint dwClusterHighestVersion;
    public uint dwClusterLowestVersion;
    public uint dwFlags;
    public uint dwReserved;

    CLUSTERVERSIONINFO()
    {
        szCSDVersion = new char[64];
        szVendorId = new char[64];
    }   
} 

public static void LosdLibraryTest()
{
    try
    {
        IntPtr hExe = LoadLibrary("clusapi.dll");
        if (hExe == IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Cannot open clusapi.dll ");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("open clusapi.dll " + hExe.ToString());

            IntPtr pAddressOfFunctionToCall = GetProcAddress(hExe, "OpenCluster");
            Console.WriteLine("open GetProcAddress " + pAddressOfFunctionToCall.ToString());

            TestOpenCluster multiplyByTen = (TestOpenCluster)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(
                                            pAddressOfFunctionToCall,
                                            typeof(TestOpenCluster));

            IntPtr resdult = multiplyByTen(null);

            Console.WriteLine("OpenCluster" + resdult.ToString());

            IntPtr ptrClusterInfo = GetProcAddress(hExe, "GetClusterInformation");
            MyFunctionDelegate drs = (MyFunctionDelegate)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(ptrClusterInfo, typeof(MyFunctionDelegate));
            uint value = 0;
            CLUSTERVERSIONINFO info = new CLUSTERVERSIONINFO();
            drs(pAddressOfFunctionToCall, "testServer", ref value, ref info);
            Console.WriteLine(info.BuildNumber);
            Console.WriteLine(info.MajorVersion);

            bool freeresult = FreeLibrary(hExe);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message+ex.StackTrace);
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please, do not include information about a language used in a question title unless it wouldn't make sense without it. Tags serve this purpose.

Comment: I recommend you also add some information what is not working, so someone may be able to answer.

Answer (score 1):

There are all sorts of errors in your code. I don't really want to go into them in much detail, but at a high level:

- The `TestOpenCluster` delegate used the wrong calling convention and the wrong character set.
- The cluster name parameter of `GetClusterInformation` is an output parameter. It returns the name to you.
- You declared `CLUSTERVERSIONINFO` as a class. Then pass it by reference. That's two levels of indirection, one too many.
- The `CLUSTERVERSIONINFO` declaration handle the arrays incorrectly.

The code is horribly complex because of the use of `LoadLibrary` and `GetProcAddress`. You should simply stop doing that. Use plain old `DllImport`. If that fails because of a missing DLL (i.e. you are on an OS without support for this API), then you'll get an exception that you can handle and inform the user in a helpful way. If for reasons unknown to us you feel compelled to use `LoadLibrary` and `GetProcAddress`, then don't do it whilst developing. Develop with `DllImport`, and only once you've got that working, switch to `LoadLibrary` and `GetProcAddress`.

Anyway, you are attempting to call two functions. First of all `OpenCluster`. Nice and easy this one:

```
[DllImport("ClusAPI.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError=true)]
public static extern IntPtr OpenCluster(string lpszClusterName);
```

Now to the struct. That should be:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet=CharSet.Unicode)]
public class CLUSTERVERSIONINFO 
{
    public uint dwVersionInfoSize;
    public ushort MajorVersion;
    public ushort MinorVersion;
    public ushort BuildNumber;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst=64)]
    public string szVendorId;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst=64)]
    public string szCSDVersion;
    public uint dwClusterHighestVersion;
    public uint dwClusterLowestVersion;
    public uint dwFlags;
    public uint dwReserved;

    public CLUSTERVERSIONINFO()
    {
        dwVersionInfoSize = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(this);
    }
}
```

And then `GetClusterInformation`. That looks like this:

```
[DllImport("ClusAPI.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Unicode)]
public static extern uint GetClusterInformation(
    IntPtr hCluster,
    StringBuilder lpszClusterName,
    ref uint lpcchClusterName,
    CLUSTERVERSIONINFO lpClusterInfo
);
```

And you can call it like this:

```
IntPtr hCluster = OpenCluster(null);
// check that hCluster is not zero

StringBuilder ClusterName = new StringBuilder(256);
uint cchClusterName = (uint)ClusterName.Capacity;
CLUSTERVERSIONINFO cvi = new CLUSTERVERSIONINFO();
uint retval = GetClusterInformation(
    hCluster, 
    ClusterName,
    ref cchClusterName,
    cvi
);
// check that retval is zero
```

I cannot test this of course, not being on a cluster. But it should get you a little further along.

Comment: Thanks David, for your thoughts. I am not good at this type of coding.Will try your solution